# css3 transform on image hover in firefox

Tags: css

```
    .mark.studio{
       background: url(../images/studio_icon.png) no-repeat;
       -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
       -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
       height: 50px;
       width: 50px;
       z-index:103 !important;
    }

    .mark.studio:hover{
       -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
      -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
       background: url(../images/studio_icon-hover.png) no-repeat;
       z-index:103 !important;

}
```

With this css on hover the image morphs from the original image to the hover image giving a really cool effect, in firefox and IE9 I just get a hover image replacement. I put the -webkit-transition in both selectors but i'm pretty sure it only needs to be in
.mark.studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the unprefixed version of `transition`; Firefox and Internet Explorer dropped the prefixes. (Note that it’s Internet Explorer **10**; IE9 doesn’t support `transition`.)

```css
.mark.studio {
    background: url(../images/studio_icon.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 103 !important;
}

.mark.studio:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/studio_icon-hover.png);
}
```

I took the liberty of taking `z-index` and `transition` off the `:hover` state; it’s pointless to add them again. (Unless you have another `z-index` with `!important` that overrides it, which would be a *really bad design*.)

Comment: interesting, i replaced it here (hover over blue star) and still does not transition http://wanderfest.com/

Comment: also if firefox dropped the prefix why did you leave -moz in the code

Comment: @alex_b: Ah, sorry, that’d be the other thing. Only Webkit can transition images like that; you’ll need two images. And I left the prefix for older versions of firefox.

Comment: so cant do anything in firefox? anything similar?

Comment: @alex_b: Like I said; use two images.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 9 doesn't support the -ms-transition tag, it only works properly on Internet Explorer 10 and up. IE10 supports both.

Comment: How could IE9 drop the prefix if it doesn’t exist in IE9? I said IE10 dropped it, which it did. :)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean! It doesn't support it, unlike your original unedited answer, which I was writing about at the time, which made it apear that it would work in IE9 id you dropped the prefix from code. And, by the way, IE10 *DOES* support the prefix. It works either way.

Comment: It supports the prefix, but it also dropped the prefix. I was just commenting on why I thought it didn't work on Firefox, but I missed the fact that it was transitioning `background-image`, which doesn’t work on either browser anyways. Nevermind! :)

Comment: Okay sorry I jumped the gun. :D