# Webkit transition on image not showing on mobile

Tags: css

this transition works fine on desktop, but on mobile the "hover" event interpreted as a tap on mobile, just makes the image disappear instead of replacing the new image. All other transitions work.

```
.mark.studio{
   background: url(../images/studio_icon.png) no-repeat;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
   transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   z-index:103 !important;
}

.mark.studio:hover{
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
  -transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 
   background: url(../images/studio_icon-hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean iOS safari? Or Chrome/browser on Android? Or both?

Comment: is the `-transition` on the `:hover` just a typo here, or on the live code as well ? Also make sure the file exists and is named right ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't own an Android phone, only iOS devices, but I do know that the transition property has very scattered support so far, when it comes to images. Like both Firefox and Internet Explorer support the transition code, but not when it is used to ease-in and out an image. I was answering, with another guy, a similar question with the transition property with background images not working, and we all came to the conclusion that it didn't work in a lot of browsers. Oh, I just looked for it, and the post was by you! [css3 transform on image hover in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016087/css3-transform-on-image-hover-in-firefox) . Well that post basically answers your question. :)

It probably won't fix it (but it's nice to try it anyways), it's pointless to repeat the transition property on hover...